# Character assignment issue with Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, encryption

I am try to assign the value to char like this

```
char Cipher1[16] = {55,149,31,253,212,158,217,64,226,62,149,241,255,147,115,155};
```

but after assigning it assign the this value to Chiper1 not exact value

```
  55 -107 31 -3 -44 -98 -39 64 -30 62 -107 -15 -1 -109 115 -101
```

is this correct assignment to char in objective c

Comment: How do you output those values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is just a difference between signed and unsigned byte ... print it in the form of unsigned char and you should get the same result.

Note: char --- is signed so value greater then 128 take 8 bits to hold -- all values greater then 128 are shown in negative(it refers to the sign bit.)

Comment: Note that whether `char` is signed or not is implementation defined.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't char signed, so hence in the range -128 to +127, so your values are being cast to signed values?

Surely you want unsigned char if you want values in the range 0 to 255?

Also agree with Vladimir, how are your ouputting the values, are you sure it's not the output that's the issue?

Comment: No I am trying to encrypt and decrypt the string using bytes and AES encryption. I got the bytes but still not able to decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

You are right now using signed char. Instead, switch to unsigned:

```
unsigned char Cipher1[16] = {55,149,31,253,212,158,217,64,226,62,149,241,255,147,115,155};
```

This will give you the correct result.